# How to automatically prevent R inputs in Sweave from running off the right margin?

Tags: r, sweave

Is it possible to get Sweave to automatically print R inputs over multiple lines ? For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth}

<<fig=TRUE>>=
plot(LakeHuron, ylab="Level in feet", xlab="Year", main="Level of Lake Huron 1875–1972", lwd=2, las=1) 
@

\end{document}
```

will print the R codes to run into (and beyond) the right hand margin. From what I can deduce,

```
<<>>=
options(width=60)
@
```

only controls R output.

Comment: Have you tried knitr, or are you tied to Sweave?

Comment: Tied to Sweave (its for a Vignette).

Comment: [Not anymore](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/). From my experience, knitr formats R input nicely.

Comment: great, i will take another look at knitr. i tried it a few months ago but hit a wall figuring out how to do references. it would still be nice to have control for the problem above in Sweave (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sweave](/questions/tagged/sweave), you can try adding the argument `keep.source = FALSE` to your code chunk, but this still won't always solve your problem by default (it didn't in this particular example).

Here is a crop of the output of what you currently have with:

```
<<fig=TRUE>>=
plot(LakeHuron, ylab="Level in feet", xlab="Year", main="Level of Lake Huron 1875–1972", lwd=2, las=1) 
@
```

[image]

Here is a crop of the output if we add `keep.source = FALSE`

```
<<fig=TRUE, keep.source=FALSE>>=
plot(LakeHuron, ylab="Level in feet", xlab="Year", main="Level of Lake Huron 1875–1972", lwd=2, las=1) 
@
```

[image]

And, here is a crop of the output if we cheat a little bit and reorder the arguments manually. Notice I've placed the problematic title as the last item:

```
<<fig=TRUE, keep.source=FALSE>>=
plot(LakeHuron, ylab="Level in feet", xlab="Year", lwd=2, las=1, main="Level of Lake Huron 1875-1972") 
@
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I do use knitr to compile .Rnw files, which provides access to some very handy code chunk options (like tidy.opts).  Using the code below, I think, might solve your text overflow problem above your figure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth}

<<fig=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(keep.blank.line=FALSE, width.cutoff=50)>>=
plot(LakeHuron, ylab="Level in feet", xlab="Year", main="Level of Lake Huron 1875–1972", lwd=2, las=1) 
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I didn't know about `tidy.opts` so knitr was also giving me some problems.

Comment: @Ananda, glad I could help, BTW THX again for your help earlier! cheers!